# whats the process to break a full character model into multiple parts?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, 3d-printing

[image][image]ok, im trying to take a full model and turn them into action figures like the following picture. i am not sure and cant find out how to remove the arms, legs and ect...is there a step or process im not understanding

Comment: Hello, we still can't see any image, do you mean it needs to be rigged and a certain moment in the animation the limbs need to be separated?

Comment: Firstly you haven't provided a picture, and secondly it depends how your model was constructed in the first place! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post and you can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to paste the link to it assuming it isn't over 30Meg.

Comment: ok i figured out how to add the photo, i have a few base mesh model characters from MB labs and would like to break them down like in the picture, one person said to use the boolean tool but im just not understanding how there making  those round curved cuts or how to select them to be separated from the body

Comment: Barring anything else, there's always the prospect of entering edit mode and manually selecting all the faces that make up the "arm", for example, and pressing P (separate) and selecting "by selection" in order to make the arm its own separate object. If you are lucky, some of the pieces may be "pre separated" as "islands" within the object, in which case you should be able to select the whole "piece" by pressing selecting a single face and then pressing L while hovering your mouse over the piece (though this may not work - it all depends on how the model was built).

Comment: thank you so much i will definitely give that a shot! yea i imported a pre made mesh model from mb labs. im not quite good enough to model my own figures yet.

Comment: is it for 3D printing?

Comment: yes it will be for 3d printing, im trying to build my own gi joe style action figures

Comment: so maybe show how your 3D character look like, the best is probably to use the existing edge loops and rip them, then add the joints

Comment: ive added the picture of the base model in trying to breakdown currently, no edits have been made as im trying to understand the breakdown process

Comment: I’ve never seen a direct procedure, but I might check for/with YouTubers or such that make toys. If nothing turns up, I’d expect the workflow would involve a pre-built hinge that is moved and scaled into place and then used to Boolean the two sides (duplicates).

Comment: thank you for your response, yea thats what led me here, ive searched and all i can seem to find on youtube was about installing ball joints, but i never though about using a prebuilt peg like that! i will definitely give it a shot!

Comment: So I guess you need to rip the edge loops (V) to cut the limbs, then create 2 pieces (male/female) that you'll put at each tip of your limbs?

Comment: yea i can definitely see that! hmm i will try and see if i can play around with it and see tomorrow morning